# Reboot and Select Boot Device after full format/install from 14.04 live cd

Tags: boot, live-cd, boot-repair

I'm trying to install 14.04.01 as a fresh OS on my laptop (previously a dual-boot of Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10). After running the live CD and selecting Install Ubuntu, I went through the whole install process (choosing to replace existing operating systems), and on rebooting without the live CD, I was asked to "Select boot device".

I loaded up the live cd again and installed the boot-repair tool. I ran this, and after restarting it successfully booted into Ubuntu once. However if I restart, I get the "Reboot and select Boot device" again. I can reproduce this process (run boot-repair from the live CD, boot successfully once, and then fail again upon restarting).

I tried completely clearing the HDD and creating a new partitioning table. The error remains the same.

The results of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): BB562B80-314C-4A8C-A804-3130164DED9B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048            4095   1024.0 KiB  8300  
   2            4096          491519   238.0 MiB   EF00  
   3          491520        32491519   15.3 GiB    8200  
   4        32491520       227803135   93.1 GiB    8300  
   5       227803136      1953523711   822.9 GiB   8300
```

Comment: I could imagine this has to do something with using both MBR and GPT partitioning tables on the same disk after reading your link. When in Ubuntu, try executing `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`, which only should provide you more information and might highlight conflicts about the GPT table. By the way, has your laptop BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - my laptop has UEFI. I just went into gparted and created a full new partition table and tried reinstalling. I'm having the same issue. :( I ran the command you gave me - results are in an edit to an original post (note: this is after redoing the partitioning table.

Comment: So UEFI works by default with GPT, but as unfortunately I am not familiar with that new stuff (ah, good old time when everybody had BIOS... sigh), you might have to wait for somebody who is experienced in this topic. Sorry I couldn't really help you :(  

Oh, stop. Maybe one last idea: Can you try searching in your UEFI for something like BIOS legacy or containing the words MBR, msdos partition, or similar things? I am only guessing as I never had a system with UEFI.

Comment: The only thing I could find was an option for Boot Mode, which I changed from UEFI Boot to CSM Boot. After that, I got `error: no such partition` followed by a grub rescue prompt.

Comment: CSM means Compatibility Support Mode and emulates a BIOS. Can you see how to enter a so-called EFI-menu where you can chose a device/partition to boot from? Is any of these options successful? Else try the ubuntu live-cd and try creating a new Partition Table, maybe then it only uses msdos-MPT that any OS should accept. By the way, is your Ubuntu 32 or 64Bit?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a solution in [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261061&p=13208643#post13208643) on the Ubuntu Forums.

> From the live cd:
>
> Use the efibootmgr to set Ubuntu to boot like Windows.
>
> ```
> sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
> ```
>
> From live installer mount the efi partition on hard drive; lines with # are comments only:
>
> ```
> #Mount efi partition. check which partition is FAT32 with boot flag. Often sda1 or sda2 but varies.
> mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
> #only if not already existing, 
> mkdir /mnt/EFI/Boot
> cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/* /mnt/EFI/Boot
> # If new folder created, the bootx64.efi will not exist, skip this command
> mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.backup
> # make grub be hard drive boot entry in UEFI. If not existing, may have to update UEFI also with efibootmgr.
> mv /mnt/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
> ```